# Use verb in sentence which begins "when"

Tags: conditional-constructions, future-tense

Which one is true: "When I have enough money, I'll buy it" or "When I have enough money I'm going to buy it".

Comment: These two sentences mean exactly the same thing. They are both grammatically correct (whether they are true or not is a different question, I assume it is not what you intended to ask). The"when" clause  not require one or another.

Answer (score 1):

**I'll = I will**

"I will" and "I am going to" are the same meaning.

However, "When I have enough money I'm going to buy it" sounds like a stronger commitment.